# set SpenSurfaceView background to transparent

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am working with the SPen and the Note 3.

I was able to set the SCanvasView to have a transparent background in the SPen SDK.

But, now I am working with the Samsung Mobile SDK, which uses SpenSurfaceView.

The goal is to overlay the surface view on top of other Views.

```
mSCanvas = new SCanvasView(this);
...
mSCanvas.setSCanvasInitializeListener(new SCanvasInitializeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitialized() {
                       ...
                    mSCanvas.setBGColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SpenPageDoc you could use:

```
mSpenPageDoc.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```